# How to access parameters from one method to another one

Tags: java, android

I'm stuck at here in this program,I want to access parameters of DatePickerFragment into TimePickerFragment.Please help.

```
public class datepicker extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datepicker);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.datepick);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timepick);

    //  TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

            // Show the date picker dialog fragment
            dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DialogFragment dFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

            // Show the time picker dialog fragment
            dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");


        }
    });


}

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, this, year, month, day);


        return dpd;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the chosen date


        Button textview = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.datepick);

        textview.setText(day + ":" + (month + 1) + ":" + year);
    }
}




public  class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get a Calendar instance
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Get the current hour and minute
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, this, hour, minute, false);
        return tpd;
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
        Button tv = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.timepick);
        tv.setText(i + ":" + i1);

        DatePickerFragment b = new DatePickerFragment();
        b.onDateSet(view ,int year,int month,int day);

    }
}}
```

I need year,month,day in TimePickerFragment method.Please solve it asap.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can user sharedpreference.

Comment: After open class declare year,month,day as variables and then assigned the corresponfidng value in the function. This variables are suposse to be available inside the class.

Comment: Need to save it into the class

Comment: create static variables for DatePickerFragment.

Comment: I used sharedpreference and worked,thanks @Muklas